# Zenmap prits all states as unknown

Tags: windows, localhost, nmap

I am trying to use Zenmap on my own machine, and it prints all port states as "unknown." None of them are shown as open or closed. I am using Windows 8.1.

```
1 tcp unknown tcpmux
2 tcp unknown compr
3 tcp unknown unknown
```

Answer (score 2):

This is due to a known limitation with scanning your own machine on Windows. The default Nmap scan type (TCP SYN scan, `-sS`) requires the ability to send and sniff raw packets. Since Microsoft removed raw sockets support from Windows in Windows XP, Nmap has to emulate it by using raw ethernet frames. Because the loopback adapter that Windows uses to address itself is not an Ethernet device, Nmap can't send and receive the special packets it needs to, and it shows all ports as "unknown." You can scan your own machine using the slower TCP Connect scan type (`-sT`).

Comment: you mean like this: nmap -sT 127.0.0.1 ??